GetAmountsOut Execution Reverted Even if pair exists Sepolia TestNet
I am trying to do swap my sepoliaETH for some token. Now when i try to get amountsOut for pairs which exists and have reserves , the txn doenst do through and gets Reverted. Below is my code.

const performBuy = async (tokenAddress, amount) => {
  try {
    const wethAddress = await routerContract.WETH();
    await getReserves(tokenAddress,wethAddress)
    // Path for WETH to Token
    const path = [  wethAddress,tokenAddress ];
    console.log(`Path: ${path}`);


    const amountIn = ethers.parseUnits('1', 18);
    
    const amountsOut = await routerContract.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path);
    console.log('Amounts Out:', amountsOut);

    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 1200;
    const tx = await routerContract.swapExactTokensForETH(
      amount, 
      0,
      path,
      wallet.address,
      deadline
    );

    console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`);
    await tx.wait();
    console.log(`Successfully bought token ${tokenAddress}`);
    

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error performing buy:',err);
  }
};

I tried Reading the source code for factory. And also tried to do on MAINET, the amountsOut works there.
I am excepting to get some reasons behind all this.
